# PHP: For loop will not execute

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I am at a complete loss. I've searched this site extensively and others as to why my for loop, among many other working loops, will not execute, and tried many suggestions. I have checked that it is in fact not executing and not failing to meet a condition for its execution. This is the loop:

```
 if (count($bunnyList)>100){
        echo "Too many bunnies! Initiating mass cull.</br>";
        for ($i=0; $i===50; $i++){
            echo 'something';
            unset ($bunnyList[rand(0,(count($bunnyList)))]);
            array_values($bunnyList);
         }
        echo 'Number of bunnies: '.(count($bunnyList));
```

The if condition executes; the first echo statement executes, and then the echo statement following the loop also executes. If the loop had been executed, then I should get a number of "something"s printed to the page, and yet I never have, even after trying tons of suggestions for other people's failed for loops. After staring at this particular piece of code for hours I'm reasonably sure I haven't messed up a piece of syntax. Please help me, I've already pulled too many chunks of my hair ou
:(

The entire code is over a hundred lines long and I didn't think it prudent to post the whole thing. In addition, all the other for loops within the program work just fine, while endless variations of this one do not.

I apologize if this is a redundant question or if it has been asked before. Other answers to questions similar to mine were not able to fix the problem. Please help me D:

TL;DR Why does only this for loop not execute within my program containing many functioning loops? The echo statements within the if condition do execute.

Comment: What is the content of $bunnylist?
add `var_dump($bunnylist);` before you loop - and post it in your topic.

Comment: Did you try  `for ($i=0; $i<=50; $i++)`

Comment: `for ($i=0; $i===50; $i++)`  test is wrong `$i < 50`

Comment: Try `for ($i=0; $i<=50; $i++){`. `In the beginning of each iteration, expr2 is evaluated. If it evaluates to TRUE, the loop continues[...]`  (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Comment: The above comments are each correct, my mistake in reading.

Comment: You are all correct. I swore I tried that variation, but I might've accidentally put > instead of < and thus thought that wasn't the problem. Another site also incorrectly labelled the for syntax as for (start value; end value; update expression) http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php5p1.html. Thank you all.

Comment: @Priyank it's not a must, however I wouldn't upvote your answer and only the answer I've edited right under here; the reason for that is because he explained it why it failed, you just gave a source.

Comment: @GeneDopuda : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp - first google search result on  `PHP For Loop` :)

Comment: @Mike M. I've done for loops for a while, but I guess I just got confused after reading the syntax on that site homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php5p1.html and having stared at the same piece of code for hours, turning my brain to mush.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38004105/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
```

Instead of:

```
for ($i = 0; $i === 50; $i++) {
```

In a for loop, the second part is NOT the ending condition, but the continuation condition. In your case it's checking if $i is equals to 50, and because it is not, it will never go in the loop.

Comment: Indeed. http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php5p1.html, a site I searched after a long while, wrongly labelled the syntax as for (start value; END value; update expression)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with php, more java, but shouldn't it for each time 'I' is less than 50, increment by 1?

```
for ($i=0; $i < 50; $i++){
    ...    
}
```

I am assuming that is the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=50; $i++){
        echo 'something';
        unset ($bunnyList[rand(0,(count($bunnyList)))]);
        array_values($bunnyList);
     }
```